# Problemt with mysql join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, mariadb, join

I have a problem with the query shown below. It always returns the same value for both snapshot and adm. Also the values returned are not what I woluld expect.

```
SELECT 
domains.name, count(snapshot_info.snapshot_uuid) as snapshot, count(users_domains.uuuid) as adm
FROM 
domains, snapshot_info, users_domains
WHERE 
domains.duuid = snapshot_info.duuid 
AND 
users_domains.duuid = domains.duuid 
group by name;
```

Returns:

```
domain1 33 33
domain2 40 40
domain3 3  3
```

This query works and returns the correct values

```
SELECT 
domains.name, count(snapshot_info.snapshot_uuid) as snapshot
FROM 
domains, snapshot_info
WHERE 
domains.duuid = snapshot_info.duuid 
group by name;
```

Returns

```
domain1 3
domain2 20
domain3 17
```

So, as you can see, the problem are introduceed when I add the users_domains join.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be useful to have a sample dataset from each table and a general table structure. It's kind of hard to debug the SQL when we don't know what the structure looks like and what the expected result should be.

Comment: Have you tried running just the second arguments of your query? Such as joining snapshot_info to user_domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use this syntax (see this question: [INNER JOIN vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)):

```
SELECT 
  domains.name,
  count(DISTINCT snapshot_info.snapshot_uuid) as snapshot,
  count(DISTINCT users_domains.uuuid) as adm
FROM 
  domains INNER JOIN snapshot_info
  ON domains.duuid = snapshot_info.duuid
  INNER JOIN users_domains
  ON users_domains.duuid = domains.duuid 
GROUP BY
  name;
```

and notice that you should use [COUNT(DISTINCT ...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) in this case.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I was missing "distinct" in my query.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, you are doing a CROSS JOIN between `domains, snapshot_info, users_domains`.

If the second query runs right for you, maybe you are duplicating rows between `domains` and `users_domains`, so you will need another field to join these table to don't duplicate, because the join `users_domains.duuid = domains.duuid` is insufficient.

However, try this:

```
SELECT 
     domains.name,
     count(distinct snapshot_info.snapshot_uuid) as snapshot,
     count(distinct users_domains.uuuid) as adm
FROM 
     users_domains
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     domains 
     ON users_domains.duuid = domains.duuid 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     snapshot_info
     ON domains.duuid = snapshot_info.duuid 
group by name;
```

Comment: Thank you! This query is correct, exept that it returns the same values as my original query. The problem is missing "distinct". See accepted answer below.

Comment: Ok, if you want only distinct values you're right. Thanks by appreciation